# Bind dynamic columns to a table using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting some data from an external service and I am trying to show it on a table. The problem is that the data I get from service will be with dynamic columns, some times there will be 5 column another time 8. I don't know how I could handle it in ng-repeat. and using things like [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) won't be a good solution I think as there will be only 10 rows to display. for this If I use any external solution that will be a overhead. Is there any angular method to achieve this? if not what is the best option for this small data.

Note: Column names will also be dynamic
My code

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="prdElement in packageElement track by $index" class="package-grid">
    <table class="hovertable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Line #</th>
                <th>Quantity in Plt</th>
                <th>Allready Packed</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in prdElement.Data" ng-init="data.newquantity  = 0">
                <td>{{data.itemId}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{data.quantity}}
                </td>
                <td>{{data.packed}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.packageElement = [{
        name: counter,
        show: true,
        Data: [{
            name: 'item 1',
            itemId: '284307',
            quantity: '100',
            packed: 0

        }, {
            name: 'item 2',
            itemId: '284308',
            quantity: '200',
            packed: 0
        }]
    }];



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will there be the same number of columns for all data items? If so, I think you can do this.

#### 1. Define a function on your scope that gives you the object keys:

```
$scope.keys = function(obj) {
    var key;
    var keys = [];
    for (key in obj) {
        if (key === "$$hashKey") break; //angular adds new keys to the object
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
```

#### 2. use a repeater on the table header (if the objects can have different properties, you need to find the object with the highest number of properties/columns)

```
<th ng-repeat="key in keys( prdElement.Data[0] )">{{key}}</th>
```

#### 3. use a repeater on the table cell

```
<td ng-repeat="key in keys( prdElement.Data[0] )">{{ data[key] }}</td>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this. when i does this its not working